# Rendering a template variable as HTML

Tags: django, django-templates

I use the 'messages' interface to pass messages to user like this:

```
request.user.message_set.create(message=message)
```

I would like to include html in my `{{ message }}` variable and render it without escaping the markup in the template.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

If you don't want the HTML to be escaped, look at the `safe` filter and the `autoescape` tag:

[`safe`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
{{ myhtml |safe }}
```

[`autoescape`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape):

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ myhtml }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: If you need to display e.g currency signs like euro (`&euro;`), dollar passed from view this is the way to go.

Comment: Note that it is `autoescape off` and not `on`. I made that mistake and discovered it only later.

Comment: this works in 2022

Answer (score 42):

If you want to do something more complicated with your text you could create your own filter and do some magic before returning the html.
With a templatag file looking like this:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def do_something(title, content):

    something = '<h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p>' % (title, content)
    return mark_safe(something)
```

Then you could add this in your template file

```
<body>
...
    {{ title|do_something:content }}
...
</body>
```

And this would give you a nice outcome.

Comment: I see my HTML tag in the text again. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 40):

You can render a template in your code like so:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
t = Template('This is your <span>{{ message }}</span>.')

c = Context({'message': 'Your message'})
html = t.render(c)
```

See the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system) for further information.

Comment: I think I got the wrong end of the stick here, but I leave the answer for now.

Comment: I was attempting to render a page without a file only with the html content and this was the answer that was the closest to what I needed. My final code was


    return HttpResponse(Template(strHTML).render(Context({})))

Answer (score 38):

Use the [`autoescape`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) to turn HTML escaping off:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ message }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way is to use the `safe` filter:

```
{{ message|safe }}
```

Check out the [Django documentation for the safe filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe) for more information.

Answer (score 13):

No need to use the filter or tag in template. 
Just use format_html() to translate variable to html and Django will automatically turn escape off for you variable.

```
format_html("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

Check out here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html

Comment: `from django.utils.html import format_html`

Answer (score 2):

The [safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter did the work for me.
Using `{{data|safe}}` includes the html as it is.