# convert string to html code in django template

Tags: html, django, string, tags, django-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django: rendering a template variable as html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/django-rendering-a-template-variable-as-html)

I am developing a django site and I have a string variable which has html tags in it. I need that string to be read as html code on my template.

For instance if I have a string variable

description = "`<ul><li>abc</li><li>def</li><li>ghi</li></ul>`"

When I call this string variable in my template, I would like it to be displayed as

- abc
- def
- ghi

Currently it shows the string as it is.

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 74):

```
{{ description | safe }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe

more

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping

Comment: It works perfectly. I want to add a class like <li class="my-class"> to style some elements dynamically. My CSS class is ignored, How can I do it?