# Convert string to html in django

Tags: python, html, django, string, converters

I have a Django project
but I need to convert a string in Django to HTML
I try BeautifulSoup but I fail. How can I convert it?

Here is the code of views.py and HTML

```
    f= markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title))
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "fileContent": f
    })
    HTML:
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{fileContent}}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey there! I think this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786493/convert-string-to-html-code-in-django-template

Comment: But where should I put the `{{ description | safe }}`?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe  Hope the link helps.