# Django: converting Youtube URL to HTML embed code

Tags: django, youtube, embed, django-templates

I defined my custom Django filter youtube_embed_url in templatetags/custom_filters.py. It takes an Youtube url and returns the string which is embed code for the video. The code for templatetags/custom_filters.py is below:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
register = template.Library()
import re

@register.filter(name='youtube_embed_url')
# converts youtube URL into embed HTML
# value is url
def youtube_embed_url(value):
    match = re.search(r'^(http|https)\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v\=(\w*)(\&(.*))?$', value)
    if match:
        embed_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s' %(match.group(2))
        res = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"%s\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" %(embed_url)
        return res
    return ''

youtube_embed_url.is_safe = True
```

Then I use this filter in link_page.html page. Here is the relevant portion of link_page.html:

```
<div>
{{ link.url|youtube_embed_url }}
</div>
```

However, when I view the link page in browser I see the HTML code as the string:

[image]

**Any idea how to make the result of youtube_embed_url method to be interpreted as the HTML code, not a string?** Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: While we wait for a real answer, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/django-rendering-a-template-variable-as-html

Comment: This would make a cool Django snippet...

Comment: I should also note that some YouTube URLs have dashes and underscores, so your regex might need tweaking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good ol' [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).

```
{{ link.url|youtube_embed_url|safe }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [django-embed-video](https://github.com/yetty/django-embed-video).

Usage is quite similar:

```
{% load embed_video_tags %}

{{ link.url|embed:'560x315' }}
```