# Which of autoescape tag and safe filter is better to use?

Tags: django, django-templates

I was looking for a way to unescape the HTML in variables written in a Django template and I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/django-rendering-a-template-variable-as-html). So, basically there are two ways of doing it:

- Set `autoescape` to `off`:

  ```
  {% autoescape off %}{{ myHTMLstring }}{% endautoescape %}
  ```
- Using the `safe` filter:

  ```
  {{ myHTMLstring | safe }}
  ```

My question is about which one is the more adequate to use (and in which context). My feeling is that the `safe` filter is Django specific, on the contrary to the `autoescape` which seems to also used in Jinja2. But, what are your own way of thinking about it ?