# In Heroku, some link tags appear as raw HTML code

Tags: python, html, django, heroku

Once I brought my `Django` project online, some of my `HTML` tags wouldn't function. Instead, they'd display on the page as raw `HTML` code. However, when I ran the website on localhost (not on Heroku), this problem wouldn't occur. The link would display as it should.

I'm using `Python 3.4` with `Django 1.9`, and the hosting site is Heroku. Here is an image of the problem:
[image]

I inspected the source of the raw `HTML` code with the 'Inspect' tool in Chrome, and found this:
[image]

The app I'm having the problem with is llazzaro's scheduler (on GitHub), and all templates can be found there. The template indicated in the first picture has the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load scheduletags i18n %}
{% block body %}
<div class="tablewrapper">
  <div class="calendarname">{{ calendar.name }}</div>
  {% prevnext "tri_month_calendar" calendar periods.month "F Y"%}
  <div class="now">
    <a href="{% url "tri_month_calendar" calendar.slug %}">
      {% trans "This month" %}
    </a>
  </div>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">{% month_table calendar periods.month "small" -1 %}</td>
        <td width="12">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">{% month_table calendar periods.month "small" %}</td>
        <td width="12">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">{% month_table calendar periods.month "small" +1 %}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="{% url "month_calendar" calendar.slug %}{% querystring_for_date periods.month.start 2 True %}">
    {% trans "Monthly Calendar" %}
  </a>
  <a href="{% url "year_calendar" calendar.slug %}{% querystring_for_date periods.month.start 1 True %}">
    {% trans "Full Year Calendar" %}
  </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Could anyone offer some help or suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT#1**: I did some sleuthing and figured that in the code above, these two lines are the most probable causes of the problem:

```
  <div class="calendarname">{{ calendar.name }}</div>
  {% prevnext "tri_month_calendar" calendar periods.month "F Y"%}
```

For the second line of code, I found 'prevnext' as a template tag, with the code:

```
@register.inclusion_tag("schedule/_prevnext.html")
def prevnext(target, calendar, period, fmt=None):
    if fmt is None:
        fmt = settings.DATE_FORMAT
    context = {
        'calendar': calendar,
        'period': period,
        'period_name': format(period.start, fmt),
        'target': target,
    }
    return context
```

I then located '_prevnext.html', and here are its contents:

```
{% load scheduletags staticfiles %}
<div class="row row-centered">
    {% prev_url target calendar period %}
    &nbsp; <b>{{period_name}}</b> &nbsp;
    {% next_url target calendar period %}
</div>
```

'prev_url' and 'next_url' are as follows:

```
@register.simple_tag
def prev_url(target, calendar, period):
    now = timezone.now()
    delta = now - period.prev().start
    slug = calendar.slug
    if delta.total_seconds() > SCHEDULER_PREVNEXT_LIMIT_SECONDS:
        return ''

    return '<a href="%s%s"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span></a>' % (
        reverse(target, kwargs=dict(calendar_slug=slug)),
        querystring_for_date(period.prev().start, autoescape=True))


@register.simple_tag
def next_url(target, calendar, period):
    now = timezone.now()
    slug = calendar.slug

    delta = period.next().start - now
    if delta.total_seconds() > SCHEDULER_PREVNEXT_LIMIT_SECONDS:
        return ''

    return '<a href="%s%s"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a>' % (
        reverse(target, kwargs=dict(calendar_slug=slug)),
        querystring_for_date(period.next().start, autoescape=True))
```

I hope this new information helps. Thanks again, everybody.

**EDIT#2**: I looked once more at the source code of the page with the problem, and found that the HTML tags' brackets were treated as escaped characters (<):

```
<div class="row row-centered">
    &lt;a href=&quot;/main/calendar/tri_month/dd/?year=2016&amp;amp;month=2&amp;amp;day=1&amp;amp;hour=0&amp;amp;minute=0&amp;amp;second=0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
    &nbsp; <b>March 2016</b> &nbsp;
    &lt;a href=&quot;/main/calendar/tri_month/dd/?year=2016&amp;amp;month=4&amp;amp;day=1&amp;amp;hour=0&amp;amp;minute=0&amp;amp;second=0&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
</div>
```

Somehow, the HTML code returned through the Python functions don't actually carry through. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please attach your template.

Comment: Have you installed `bower` on Heroku?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the right template; your screenshot includes things like `<span class="glyphicon...">` and `<b>` which aren't in the template code.

Comment: You're right. I included the monthly view's template instead of the 3-month view. Sorry

Comment: @vishes_shell Bower is installed, yes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The template's been corrected and I've added some additional information. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. So now I think we need the code for the `prev_url` and `next_url` template tags.

Comment: All right, it's up now.

Comment: Could anybody please offer some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/rendering-a-template-variable-as-html) regarding returning HTML through template tags. I changed the template code to

```
{% autoescape off %}{% prevnext "tri_month_calendar" calendar periods.month "F Y"%}{% endautoescape %}
```

and it worked.

It turns out I was wrong in the beginning, and it wasn't the Python's code's fault. Instead, the template took the contents of the output of `prevnext` and escaped all of the special characters.

However, I still don't understand why the template tags had no problem when I ran the project locally; the tags weren't escaped. At least the problem has been fixed.