# Python convert json/html to pdf

Tags: python, html, json, pdf

I'm writing a script for converting a json file with html, into a rendered pdf.
I wrote this:

```
from weasyprint import HTML  
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.loader import render_to_string, get_template
import json


context = json.load(open("source path"))

rendered_string = render_to_string("template.html", context)

HTML(string=rendered_string).write_pdf("sample.pdf")
```

The problem is the output, all the html in the json is formatted as simple text and in bond type... the json part is ok.
Someone knows how can i solve this?

this is the template:

```
{%for elemento in elementi%}
 {%if not elemento.tipo%}
   <h1>{{elemento.html}}</h1>
 {%else%}
   <ul>
   {%for f in elemento.form %}
     <li>{{f}}</li>
   {%endfor%}
   </ul>
 {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

and this is the json:

```
{"elementi":[{"id":107729,"titolo":null,"tipo":false,"form":null,"html":"<span lessico='Questa' idx=\"0\" testo=\"testo\" show-modal=\"setModal()\" tables=\"updateTables(input)\">Questa</span> <span lessico='&egrave;' idx=\"1\" testo=\"testo\" show-modal=\"setModal()\" tables=\"updateTables(input)\">&egrave;</span> <span lessico='una' idx=\"2\" testo=\"testo\" show-modal=\"setModal()\" tables=\"updateTables(input)\">una</span> <span lessico='domanda' idx=\"3\" testo=\"testo\" show-modal=\"setModal()\" tables=\"updateTables(input)\">domanda</span>...","traduci":[],"inputLessicale":[],"esercizioId":101624,"italiano":null,"testo_principale":"Questa &egrave; una domanda...","testo_principale_pre":"","testo_principale_post":"","risposta_1":"","risposta_2":"","risposta_3":"","risposta_4":"","distrattore_1":"","distrattore_2":"","distrattore_3":"","distrattore_4":"","parole_gia_ricostruite":"","continua":false,"focus":true,"ignora_lessico":false,"etichetta_1":null,"etichetta_2":null,"etichetta_3":null,"etichetta_4":null,"etichetta_5":null},
{"id":107730,"titolo":"Scegli la risposta corretta","tipo":"M","form":["a scelta multipla","con risposta aperta","di tipo trova","di associazione"],"html":null,"traduci":[],"inputLessicale":[],"esercizioId":101624,"italiano":null,"testo_principale":"a scelta multipla","testo_principale_pre":"","testo_principale_post":"","risposta_1":"","risposta_2":"","risposta_3":"","risposta_4":"","distrattore_1":"con risposta aperta","distrattore_2":"di associazione","distrattore_3":"di tipo trova","distrattore_4":"","parole_gia_ricostruite":"","continua":false,"focus":false,"ignora_lessico":false,"etichetta_1":null,"etichetta_2":null,"etichetta_3":null,"etichetta_4":null,"etichetta_5":null}],"ordine_in_verifica":null}
```

Comment: Asking for html rendering issues with weasyprint might be addressed faster using their own means of communication. (IRC and GitHub)

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is weasyprint, I think i did something wrong in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a safety feature of Django to avoid HTML injection, see this answer from a similar thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4848661/1047040

Instead of:

```
{{ elemento.html }}
```

Use this:

```
{{ elemento.html | safe }}
```

From the Django docs:

Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe