# Django template with html tag in jinja2

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I use CKEditor in my django project to take bio details from user.
When I display user data on front end, It show with html tag.
How to I remove tag from front end & give display effect of that tag?

```
 {% for user in user_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
                <td>{{user.dob}}</td>
                <td>{{user.hobbies}}</td>
                <td>{{user.message}}</td>
                <td>{{user.bio}}</td>
```

its shows as this:

```
<p><em><strong>Bio</strong></em></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering a template variable as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/rendering-a-template-variable-as-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `{{user.bio|safe}}` instead of `{{user.bio}}`.