# Passing html to index.html template from view in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my code in get_rand.py

```
def okdoo(request):
   context = {'index': "<div> sadsadsadasd </div>"}
   render(request, "index.html", context)
```

This is my code in views.py

```
def index(request):
    okdoo(request)
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

This is my code in index.html:

```
{{index}}
```

No text is showing up when i try loading it....

Comment: possibly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4848661/8135079

Comment: Show us the full view code, `render(request, "index.html", context)` as a standalone line doesn't make sense.

Comment: simply a method receiving request variable from another view.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**
**You miss a return function**

```
def okdoo(request):
   context = {'index': "<div> sadsadsadasd </div>"}
   return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

make sure to join templates with **base dir** in your `settings.py`

You Can Do Via this Code:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'your directory')
```

Then find this in your `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: @user2353418 but you also need to join with base_dir

Comment: It doesn't work. Updated situation details in question. I feel the line "return render(request, "index.html")" is overwriting okdoo(request)

Answer (score 0):

change your views.py

```
def okdoo(request):
    context = {'index': "<div> sadsadsadasd </div>"}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```