# Prettify html page in django

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I was making this Django website and it does just what I want. But now I need to output the HTML code with indentation to an HTML page. I have used `bs4` `s `.prettify()` method but it only shows the indented code on the console. This is my `views.py` main function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from . forms import InForm


def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            you = form.cleaned_data.get('you')
            htm = requests.get(you)
            dat = soup(htm.content, 'html.parser').prettify()
            print(dat)
            return render(request, 'main.html', {'dat':dat})
    else:
        form = InForm()
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'form':form})
```

the output I get:

[image]

`` I`m using an android emulator for the project ``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering a template variable as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848611/rendering-a-template-variable-as-html)

Comment: yeah. thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

For indentation purpose you need css help

style.css

```
.article{
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

main.html

```
<div class="article">
{{dat}}
</div>
```